# Selenium exception HTML POST

Tags: selenium, exception, testing

I don't understand why this code is giving me an exception when I try to run it:

```
//import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.commands.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
public class One {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.com");
        selenium.start();   
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.windowMaximize();
    }
}
```

Which produces the following exception:

> Exception
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
>       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:114)
>       at One.main(One.java:13)
>       Caused by: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
>       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:111)
>       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getCommandResponseAsString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:185)
>       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.executeCommandOnServlet(HttpCommandProcessor.java:120)
>       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:100)
>       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:277)
>       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.start(HttpCommandProcessor.java:239)
>       at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:105)
>       ... 1 more

Comment: Any reason you are using all deprecated methods?

Comment: No idea where have you got the idea of starting Selenium WebDriver instance that way but either that's some old and deprecated version or some 3rd party customization. Just following the instruction on Selenium official webpage